# Is it possible to create a file with a fixed size in linux?

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I need a function which will create a file with fixed size in linux. Function like `truncate` or `fopen,fseek,fclose`, is not a solution because, they will fill opened file with zeros, but it is not necessary and I have no time for this. So is there some function, which will only open a file with fixed length and not fill buffer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system call [`truncate(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/truncate.2.html) **doesn't fill the file with zeros**. It simply advances the file's reported size and leaves holes in it.

When you read from it, you *do* get zeros, but that's just a convenience of the OS.

> The truncate() and ftruncate() functions cause the regular file named
>   by path or referenced by fd to be truncated to a size of precisely
>   length bytes.
>
> If the file previously was shorter, it is extended, and the extended
>   part **reads as null bytes ('\0')**.

About holes (from TLPI):

> The existence of holes means that a file’s **nominal size** may be larger
>   than the amount of disk storage it utilizes (in some cases,
>   considerably larger).

Filesystems and holes:

> Rather than allocate blocks of null bytes for the holes in a file, **the
>   file system can just mark** (with the value 0) appropriate pointers in
>   the i-node and in the indirect pointer blocks to indicate that they
>   don't refer to actual disk blocks.

As [Per Johansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622060/per-johansson) notes, this is dependent of the filesystem.

> Most native UNIX file systems support the concept of file holes, but
>   many nonnative file systems (e.g., Microsoft’s VFAT) do not. On a
>   file system that doesn’t support holes, explicit null bytes are
>   written to the file.

Comment: ...provided the filesystem supports it, but ext2/3/4 does.